# Android Touch Animation Effect

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, touch, effect

I would like to create an animation effect whenever the user touches the screen with their finger in my android app.  Whenever they touch the screen at a certain coordinate I would like it to appear that pixels are shooting out in every direction then they quickly disappear.  The pixels should be a different color than the background.  If the user drags their finger on the screen I would like pixels to shoot out as they drag their finger.  Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Comment: I have a feeling I will need a transparent bitmap that goes over my layout.  Then every time the user touches the screen I will need to create the effect by constantly redrawing the bitmap.  I'm not sure if this would work. I haven't done much bitmap programming in android.

Comment: Have you done this, I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 0):

Implement Gestures in the view and pass the tounch events to the gesture. 
In Gesture you will have the callback methods like

1. onDown(MotionEvent e)
2. onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent
   e2, float distanceX,float distanceY)
3. onShowPress(MotionEvent e)

Each of it contains a MotionEvent object. you can get current X and Current Y position on the screen.

Comment: I know how to get the coordinates of a screen touch.  You don't necessarily have to use gestures.  I am more interested in how to create the animation effect once you know the coordinates.